# Editing a Readymade Template: Content Alignment and Responsiveness Issues

Tags: php, html, css, responsive, project

I'm currently working on a project where I need to customize a readymade template to meet my project requirements. However, I'm encountering a couple of challenges.

Firstly, after editing the template, certain content isn't aligning correctly or setting as intended. Additionally, the responsiveness of the template seems to be compromised after my edits.

I've checked the documentation and reviewed the code, but I'm still facing these issues. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve these problems? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!